# copy to clipboard in JavaScript from row data

Tags: javascript, html, copy

```js
function copyPaste(number) {
        /* Get the text field */
      var copyText = number;

      /* Select the text field */
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

      /* Copy the text inside the text field */
      document.execCommand("copy");

      /* Alert the copied text */
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyText);
    }
```

```html
<th><p id="phone" onclick="copyPaste(<?php echo $row['phone'];?>)"><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></p></th>
```

I was working without `<p>` tag. It wasn't working also.. Error : `Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function at copyPaste ((index):109) at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick` from console. I was following [the course](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Comment: In that course, `copyText` is an element (`document.getElementById("myInput")`), not the text you want to copy

Comment: @brombeer Oh! Yeah...

Comment: @brombeer I am not getting how to do that... Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` is a method of `HTMLInputElement`. Currently, `copyText` is a string. To use `copy` command, you need to create dummy input in Html.

```
function copyPaste(number) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("input");

  // Add it to the document
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);

  // Set value of input 
  dummy.value = number;

  /* Select the text field */
  dummy.select();
  dummy.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  // Remove it as its not needed anymore
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + number);
}
```

Comment: What's `dummy_id`?

Comment: Actually, we don't need it. I edited my answer. Here the key is to use dummy element.

Comment: Why should we make a new element when we can just use the `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` function?

Comment: @Prime Your earlier code was working but, new code isn't... Why?

Comment: @McconnellMelany, it should work. Will you try again?

Comment: Yeah. it worked. Thanks. really good unique and creative idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you're trying to copy a number, but the copyPaste() function from the w3 tutorial is meant to be called with an element. If you want to copy a text, [`navigator.clipboard.writeText()` (MDN link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) is your friend. This is how you use it:

```js
function copyPaste(number) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(number)
  alert(`The Number ${number} was copied.`)
}
```

EDIT: The code wont work in a JS console, because the page needs to be in focus. If you implement it on the webpage, it should work.

Comment: Oh! This is more beautiful answer.. :) <3 .. You didn't write `;`.. Can I run JS code without colon..? I heard that there's an update in JS.. So, I want to know cause, you didn't write... .?\

Comment: In my earlier comment I said that this answer is beautiful cause, you just finished the whole code in twice line. But, when I run that in my code I notice I am getting alert message but, unable to copy...

Comment: Yeah, the semicolons are optional in JS. BTW if it helped you, you can mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: Oh yeah, if you run it from your console, it cant copy it, because the window isn't focused (the page itself needs to be focused, or it isnt allowed to modify the clipboard). Try implementing it on the page and it should work.

Comment: No! I didn't run it from console. I just changed my function...

Comment: Just tested it on my webpage, works on my end.